# SSIS not running in SQL JOB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job, sql-agent

I have a problem with SQL JOB.

I am using SSIS to import data into database. While I am running SSIS through Visual studio it works as expected. Also when I am running the SSIS from Integration Services Catalogues in SQL Server, it works fine. But my issue is that when I am trying to import data into my DB using SQL JOB (using the same SSIS as in previous cases), although there is no error message and Sql job runs with success, the destination  table in my DB is empty (no data are imported into my DB).

When I checked the execution report for SSIS, run by SQL I see this warning:”Foreach Loop Container: Warning: The for each file enumerator is empty. The for each file enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.” 
Once again, everything works OK when I am running SSIS in other way than by using SQL JOB.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this problem? Please help me, because I am not able to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say without more information, but I'd make sure that that windows account running the task has access to that folder where you have a file enumerator...

Comment: Are you using a local or UNC path in your package? (i.e. does it start with `\\servername` or `D:\` Possibly it is not looking at the path you expect.

Comment: Does the service account from which SQL Job is running has the access on the directory where files are located?